# Using reledpar, how do I break long paragraphs on page break?

Tags: reledpar, parallel-texts

I want to typeset a text along with its translation.
When I use reledpar, if a paragraph is long, it's not broken when a page breaks, and the whole paragraph is moved to the next page. This leaves a lot of blank space at the bottom of the page.

[image]

The manual says:

> reledmac essentially puts each chunk of numbered text (the text within
> a \pstart . . . \pend) into a box and then following the \pend
> extracts the text line by line from the box to number and print it.

Can I somehow break paragraphs, although boxes are used?

---

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

%opening
\title{Bilingual example}
\author{}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\numberlinefalse

\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    
    \pstart
    \eledsection{Section}
    \pend
    
    \pstart
    After walking two or three times along that part of the lane, she was tempted, by the pleasantness of the morning, to stop at the gates and look into the park. The five weeks which she had now passed in Kent had made a great difference in the country, and every day was adding to the verdure of the early trees. She was on the point of continuing her walk, when she caught a glimpse of a gentleman within the sort of grove which edged the park; he was moving that way; and, fearful of its being Mr. Darcy, she was directly retreating.
    After walking two or three times along that part of the lane, she was tempted, by the pleasantness of the morning, to stop at the gates and look into the park. The five weeks which she had now passed in Kent had made a great difference in the country, and every day was adding to the verdure of the early trees. She was on the point of continuing her walk, when she caught a glimpse of a gentleman within the sort of grove which edged the park; he was moving that way; and, fearful of its being Mr. Darcy, she was directly retreating.
    \pend
    
    \pstart
    \eledsection{Section 2}
    \pend
    
    \pstart
    After walking two or three times along that part of the lane, she was tempted, by the pleasantness of the morning, to stop at the gates and look into the park. The five weeks which she had now passed in Kent had made a great difference in the country, and every day was adding to the verdure of the early trees.
    \pend
    
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    
    \pstart
    \eledsection{Seccion}
    \pend
    
    \pstart
    After walking two or three times along that part of the lane, she was tempted, by the pleasantness of the morning, to stop at the gates and look into the park. The five weeks which she had now passed in Kent had made a great difference in the country, and every day was adding to the verdure of the early trees. She was on the point of continuing her walk, when she caught a glimpse of a gentleman within the sort of grove which edged the park; he was moving that way; and, fearful of its being Mr. Darcy, she was directly retreating.
    \pend
    
    \pstart
    \eledsection{Seccion 2}
    \pend
    
    \pstart
    After walking two or three times along that part of the lane, she was tempted, by the pleasantness of the morning, to stop at the gates and look into the park. The five weeks which she had now passed in Kent had made a great difference in the country, and every day was adding to the verdure of the early trees. She was on the point of continuing her walk, when she caught a glimpse of a gentleman within the sort of grove which edged the park;
    \pend
    
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns
\end{document}
```

Comment: YOu should use \ledpb.